# TMUX using HJKL to navigate panes

Tags: tmux

Standard TMUX is set to use ctrl-b + [up, down, left, right] when navigating between panes.

I would like to make it so that I can use ctrl-b (or the prefix of my choice) + [h,j,k,l].

I thought I had done this with the following vi key in my `~/.tmux.conf` settings:

```
set -g status-keys vi
setw -g mode-keys vi
```

Yet this didn't seem to change anything (at least not what I was looking for). How can I get this to work. And yes my `.tmux.conf` is working properly. I can provide more info if needed.

Update:

Here is my full .tmux.conf after trying to get it to work:

```
set -g status-keys vi
setw -g mode-keys vi

set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind C-a send-prefix


# smart pane switching with awareness of vim splits
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

Alternatively, I have tried using this w/ vim-tmux-navigator Vim plugin:

```
# smart pane switching with awareness of vim splits
bind -n C-h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L"
bind -n C-j run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-j) || tmux select-pane -D"
bind -n C-k run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-k) || tmux select-pane -U"
bind -n C-l run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-l) || tmux select-pane -R"
bind -n C-\ run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys 'C-\\') || tmux select-pane -l"
```

[source](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/seamlessly-navigate-vim-and-tmux-splits)

Which also doesn't work either. I am a bit stumped.

Comment: If you're willing to put in the work, try what is written up in these articles: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/seamlessly-navigate-vim-and-tmux-splits , https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator , http://www.codeography.com/2013/06/19/navigating-vim-and-tmux-splits

Comment: you meant navigate **windows** or **panes** in tmux ? btw, this is not a vim question, I am removing the vim tag.

Comment: I have updated my question. I meant panes, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 100):

You can do this as follows:

```
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

Note that `mode-keys` refers to using vi-like navigation within a buffer and `status-keys` refers to using vi-like editing within the status bar, but neither refers to switching between panes.

Comment: Ah I see. Hm this doesn't seem to work. Perhaps I need to unbind something? prefix-l still tries to go to last window, the rest don't work either.

Comment: @ApathyBear Using the above four lines only as my `.tmux.conf` does indeed get me the desired behavior. Prefix+{h,j,k,l} to navigate between panes. What version of tmux are you using?

Comment: I am using tmux 2.0. I have also updated my question with more information.

Comment: Also works on my system (OSX Yosemite; tmux 2.0). I implemented this config from a github user: https://gist.github.com/rssvihla/789284.

Comment: What is prefix in this context?

Comment: prefix in this context is tmux's prefix, ctrl+b by default

Answer (score 22):

Did you remember to source your ~/.tmux.conf file?  After making any changes in this file you need to enter the following command to see any of the changes take place

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

The Micah Smith's answer seems to work. But it doesn't have quite the same behaviour that we have with the arrow keys. With the arrows, if you are fast enough, you can hit prefix + arrow key multiple times and you are able to navigate multiple panes, using the *same* prefix hiy. Main difference:

**With the arrows:**

```
// to move 3 panes to the right
prefix + -> -> ->
```

**With this hack:**

```
// to move 3 panes to the right
(prefix + l) 3x
```

Still, to make this change, you need to update your `~/.tmux.conf` file and then restart tmux sessions.
To be sure you don't have  any tmux sessions you can run

```
$ tmux list-sessions
```

If you have some sessions running, run `$ killall tmux` and you should be good to go.

This☝️ was tested in a macbook, it should be the same for linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a modal mode for tmux (e.g. like in Vim text editor), there is a plugin [tmux-modal](https://github.com/whame/tmux-modal) that can be used to execute complex commands with just a few keystrokes. For example:

`w h` to select the left pane

`w j` to select the pane below

`w k` to select the pane above

`w l` to select the right pane

There is also a *sticky* mode (`w w`) that enables `h`, `j`, `k`, `l` to select the panes as you want to, without a prefix key. Please see the [repository](https://github.com/whame/tmux-modal) for more information.