# Trying to get vim-like pane navigation in tmux (hjkl)

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm trying to set the following keybindings to get similar pane navigation as vim. I tried the following in my tmux.conf file, but it ends up just making it so I can't use hjkl at all (even when just normally trying to type on the command line).

```
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/30719312/413254)

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I'm in iTerm2 ssh'ing into a Ubuntu box in case that's of any relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was making a rookie mistake and just needed to restart the tmux server.

### What I was doing:

1 - Added to .tmux.conf

```
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

2 - created a new tmux session `> tmux new -s test`

3 - sourced the .tmux-conf `> source .tmux.conf.`

This is apparently a very wrong way to do things and resulted in the really odd behavior I described in my question where I couldn't use those keys at all.

### What I should have done:

1 - Added to .tmux.conf

```
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

2 - `> tmux kill-server`

3 - `> tmux new -s test`